# Подойдёт ли материнка под процесор, если нет то подскажите как мне понять которая подойдёт

Tags: windows, железо

Я вот планирую прикупить "Ryzen 3 4100"

А на материнку выбор пал "ASRock A520M-HVS"

Вот только разрываюсь в непонимании к поколениеям, пишет что только в материнку можно всунуть 3-е поколение. Если не подойдёт то можете простыи языком объяснить что такое поколения и как мне самому можно определить подходит ли материнка для процесора

PS.проверял совместимы ли они на сайте "nerdpart.com/ru/configurator"
вроде всё впорядке, но хочу быть уверен

Comment: Нужно смотреть, чтобы BIOS был не ниже версии P2.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Список поддерживаемых процессоров](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/A520M-HVS/index.ru.asp#CPU)

```
AM4 Ryzen 3 4100(100-000000510) 65W Renoir  4GHz    2MB     P2.10
```

Нужно смотреть, чтобы BIOS был не ниже версии P2.10